# wordpress jquery 3d plugin not loading

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress, 3d

i need help implanting my jquery script in wordpress.
I already linked everything in function.php (wp_enquere_scripts) and i checked it, both js load.
Now i have a problem not displaying what i would like to and I have no idea why...is it possible that my source-link is wrong?

here the code (its a 3d model viewer with images)

```
<div class="wpb_wrapper">
        <script type="text/javascript">      $('.wpb_wrapper').spritespin({
    source: SpriteSpin.sourceArray('/img/rad_zoom_{frame}.jpg', { frame: [1,34], digits: 3}),
    width: 1100,
    height: 770,
    sense: -1,
    mods: ['move', 'zoom', '360'],
    autostart: false,
    behavior: null,
    module: null
  });
```

here the link of the official plugin:
http://www.jqueryscript.net/other/Versatile-jQuery-Product-Image-Viewer-Plugin-SpriteSpin.html

maybe you guys know a better way putting this onto a wordpress-site

thanks

Comment: Errors on the console? Are the other scripts loaded before you script (aka is `$` defined, when you call it)?

Comment: consol says "Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function" at:"  $('.wpb_wrapper').spritespin({"

Comment: So, I guess, jQuery is loaded after your script. Best solution: put your code in a separate JS file and use `wp_enqueue_script()` with a dependency for jQuery.

Comment: Thanks it works now (well at least i can see it haha) but its terrible flashing and looks pretty ugly not as the example showed? Why?

Comment: Maybe some CSS missing?

Comment: Awesome it perfectly fits now thanks so much ;) you helped a lot